# Fetch JSON from several URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mocha

The exercise is Write a JavaScript package that is able to:

1. fetch an array of URLs which contain JSON data
2. return their contents in a promise

I have already made a solution to this exercise, but I would like some input on how to improve this solution in terms of efficiency, security and complexity. I have also included unit tests for this solution.

**index.js**

```
const { InvalidParameterError, EmptyArrayError, InvalidURLError, FetchError, APIError } = require("./errors");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const validUrl = require('valid-url');

const links = [
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ftse-fsi.json', 
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json', 
    'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-usd.json'
]

/** 
 * iterates through the array and fetches data from each url, includes edge cases
 * @params {urls} array of URLs
 * @return {Promise} promise which is an array of the data fetched from the URL in JSON format

 */
function requestMultipleUrls (urls) {
    if (!Array.isArray(urls)){
        console.log('Parameter passed is not in array format', urls)
        return new InvalidParameterError('urls should be inside in an array')
    }

    if (urls.length === 0) {
        console.log('Array cannot be empty', urls)
        return new EmptyArrayError('Array of urls cannot be empty')
    }

    const promises =  urls.map(async (url) => {
        if ((!validUrl.isUri(url))) {
            console.log('URL is in incorrect format', url)
            return new InvalidURLError('Input URL is not in the correct format')
        }

        try {
            const data = await fetch(url);
            const { status } = data
            
            if (status !== 200) {
                console.log(`Your fetch call returned a status code of ${status}, check if the URL you entered is correct`)
                return new APIError('Something went wrong with the URL you are trying to fetch', status)
            } else {
                return mapData(data)
            }
            
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return new FetchError('Something went wrong during the fetch call')
        }
    })

    return Promise.all(promises)
}


/** 
 * Deconstructs the data being passed to form an object that is eventually returned
 * @params {data} response that is recieved from the fetch call in requestMultipleUrls
 * @return {final} object that is formatted
 */
const mapData = async (data) => {
    const {url, status} = data
    const final =  {
        url,
        status,
        body: await data.json()
    }
    return final
}

requestMultipleUrls(links).then((data) => console.log(data))

module.exports = {
    requestMultipleUrls
}
```

**errors.js**

```
class InvalidParameterError {
    constructor (message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class EmptyArrayError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class InvalidURLError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 400;
        this.message = message
    }
}

class APIError {
    constructor(message, status){
        this.status = status,
        this.message = message
    }
}

class FetchError {
    constructor(message) {
        this.status = 502;
        ths.message = message
    }
}

module.exports = {
    InvalidParameterError,
    EmptyArrayError,
    InvalidURLError,
    FetchError,
    APIError
}
```

**index.spec.js**

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { requestMultipleUrls } = require('../index');
const gbpUsd = require('./gbp-usd.json');
const gbpHkd = require('./gbp-hkd.json')

describe('requestMultipleUrl intended functionality', () => {
    it('function should return an accumulated API response', async () => {
    const dummyUrls = [
            'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-usd.json',
            'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json'
    ]
    const promise = await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls);
    expect(promise).to.deep.equal([gbpUsd, gbpHkd]);
    }) 
})

describe('requestMultipleUrl edge cases', () => {
    it('should throw an error if the urls in the array do not match URI standards', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = [
            'lfkjklwfklm',
            'ekefjkf;lfl;'
        ]

        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Input URL is not in the correct format')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if URL array is empty', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = []
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Array of urls cannot be empty')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if the parameter being passed is not an array', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = 'https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-hkd.json'
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch (error) {
            expect(error.message).to.eql('urls should be inside in an array')
        }
    })

    it('should throw an error if status code is not 200', async () => {
        const dummyUrls = ['https://ft-tech-test-example.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gbp-jpy.json']
        try {
            await requestMultipleUrls(dummyUrls)
        } catch(error){
            expect(error.message).to.eql('Something went wrong with the URL you are trying to fetch')
        }
    })
})
```